# Get Parent object from child object in Python 3.10

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I have a child and parent class. I want to get the parent object from the child object.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, property1):
        self.property1 = property1

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, property1, property2):
        super().__init__(property1)
        self.property2 = property2
        
    def get_parent(self):
        return super()

b = B(property1="Value1", property2="Value2")
parent = b.get_parent()
print(parent.property1)
```

I get an error :
`AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'property1'`

How can I solve the issue ?

**EDIT**

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, property1):
        self.property1 = property1
        
    def get_A(self):
        return self
        
        def get_A2(self):
            return A(self.property1)
    
        class B(A):
            def __init__(self, property1, property2):
                super().__init__(property1)
                self.property2 = property2
        
        b = B(property1="Value1", property2="Value2")
        
    # what I want but don't work
parent = b.get_A()
print(type(parent))
print(parent.property1)
print(parent.property2)

# what works but requires using the constructor of A again
parent = b.get_A2()
print(type(parent))
print(parent.property1)
print(parent.property2)
```

Returns

```
<class '__main__.B'>
Value1
Value2
<class '__main__.A'>
Value1

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[77], line 27
     25 print(type(parent))
     26 print(parent.property1)
---> 27 print(parent.property2)

AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'property2'
```

Type is still B not A... How can I avoid have to recreate A from B using the constructor ?

Comment: It is not useful to `return super()`. What is wrong with just `print(b.property1)`?

Comment: _"I want to get the parent object"_ there is no such thing. `b` is _one_ object of type `B`. You can use `B` _as-if_ it were an `A` (see [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)), but there's no way to get an object `o` from `b` such that `type(o) is A`.

Comment: There is no such thing as "child object" or "parent object". From the `b` instance, you can just do `b.property1` to get a property that was assigned in the parent class.

Comment: Did you mean to `print(type(parent))`?

Comment: There is no separate `A` instance in the `B` instance. This isn't like C++, with base class subobjects.

Comment: So, when you construct an A you find it doesn't have property2

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your use case is, but this works, as I ignore the function that returns super():

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, property1):
        self.property1 = property1

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, property1, property2):
        super().__init__(property1)
        self.property2 = property2
        
    def get_parent(self):
        return super()

b = B(property1="Value1", property2="Value2")
parent = b.property1
print(parent)
```

console prints: Value1

As another note, printing "super()" would show:

<super: <class 'B'>, >

which isnt useful.